# Silex - Listeners not executed when dispatching from a test

Tags: symfony, testing, silex

I've written a class to load some fixtures in DB each time a functional test is executed. These fixtures are created calling a service which after creating some data, dispatches an event so that other data is created from listeners. The problem is that the listeners are not executed when loading the fixtures.

Do I need to mock all events dispatches to make the listeners to be executed? I mean, dispatching manually the desired events from the fixtures load method? Why aren't listeners executed?

```
abstract class APITest extends WebTestCase
{
    protected $app;

    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../../app.php';
        require __DIR__ . '/../../controllers.php';
        require __DIR__ . '/../../routing.php';
        $app['debug'] = true;
        unset($app['exception_handler']);
        $app['session.test'] = true;

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        /* @var $app Application */
        $app = $this->app;
        $fixtures = new TestingFixtures($app);
        $fixtures->load();
    }

    ...
}
```

The subscribers are registered from `app.php` with:

```
$app->register(new SubscribersServiceProvider());
```

And in `SubscribersServiceProvider`:

```
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;

class SubscribersServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * { @inheritdoc }
     */
    public function register(Application $app)
    {

    }

    /**
     * { @inheritdoc }
     */
    public function boot(Application $app)
    {

        /* @var $dispatcher EventDispatcher */
        $dispatcher = $app['dispatcher'];

        $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new CustomSubscriber($app['foo'], $app['mailer'], $app['monolog']));
        //... more subscribers
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to share more code. Where do you attach your listeners? Where do you dispatch the event?

Comment: @mTorres - I've added more code. The events are dispatched using the `dispatch` method inside the service used by the testing fixtures.

Comment: Just wild guess, but do you boot your app inside your tests?

Comment: @mTorres - You're right. I was not calling `$app->boot()`. Now it works. Thank you! You can add an answer if you want. I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `$app->boot()` in the tests as the subscribers are added when the application boots.